# How to make make constraint apply to all rows in joined table?

Tags: mysql

Let's say I have two tables like the following:

[image]

I want to find users who have no items, meaning they either have no items associated with their user_id in the items table, or if they do then the **all** the quantities of those items must be 0.

If I do:

`SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name FROM user LEFT JOIN item ON item.user_id = user.id WHERE item.quantity='0' OR item.id IS NULL`

The results will include both John and Bob, since Bob has no items in the items table and John has some items with 0 quantity. But I don't want John to be included in the results because he has an item with quantity = 1.

How can I create an SQL query with a condition to ensure all the item quantities must be 0 and therefore omit John from the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user.id, user.name 
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM item i WHERE u.id = i.user_id AND i.quantity > 0)
)
```

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to do this without a nested select? The real-world scenario would involve a query with several of these conditions and the database is very large, and I'm aware nested selects incur a performance penalty.

Comment: generally, `NOT EXISTS` performs well when using indexed columns